# Using the grooveshark API with html5 audio tags

Tags: api, html, html5-audio, grooveshark

Are you able with the grooveshark api to get a songs data and play it with the html5 audio tag? Or something similar..

I don't seem to understand how the API actually works - do I get data or just a link to grooveshark for the given song?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without access to the Grooveshark Public API it is not possible - only possible to search songs, users, playlists ect.

Another thing is the Javascript API which is used by injecting the Javascript to the Grooveshark page which isn't what I was looking for...